# Python: Removing multiple for loops for faster calculation (centered l2 discrepancy)

Tags: python

The equation I need to calculate is as below:

[image]

(where, nexp is the number of sample points and ndv is the number of design variables in this case)

The problem is that if I use three for loops for calculating the third term on the right, it's obviously too slow for data size that are large (I have data with size as big as (390,625 x 1000)

I have managed to reduce the loops to only one, however, it still isn't faster enough to calculate for such a huge data (the code I have managed so far is:

```
def CL2(x):
    '''Centered L2 discrepancy'''    
    nexp, ndv = x.shape

    term3 = 0
    term2 = np.sum(np.prod(1. + np.abs(x - 0.5)/2 - np.abs(x - 0.5)**2/2, axis = 1))        
    for i in range(nexp):
        term3 = term3 + np.sum(np.prod(1. + np.abs(x[i,:] - 0.5)/2 + np.abs(x - 0.5)/2 - np.abs(x[i,:] - x)/2, axis = 1))
    CL2 = (13/12)**ndv - (2*term2 - term3/nexp)/nexp    

    return CL2
```

It seems that the calculations within the loop are too complex. I have also tried to use three-dimensional matrices (by broadcasting) but it was even slower than before as the size of the matrix grew extensively large.

It doesn't matter how many for loops there are to calculate the equation but I really need it to be fast enough and at least faster than it is now.

I couldn't find any alternatives for numpy.prod where this may be the cause of the extensive calculation time.

Comment: How much do you gain if you create a matrix that is `0.5*np.abs(x-0.5)`

Comment: Could you give a minimal example that I could run timings against and show how to make it faster?

Comment: @ssm Creating an individual matrix always makes the entire code take more time, which was indeed true for this case also.

Comment: @JoonatanSamuel I would actually just create big enough x with a seed x = np.random.rand(50000, 100) and put it in the function. The time is counted using 'time' module.

Comment: @CodyChung: Not sure why that would be the case. You are doing that calculation many times. theoretically you should gain some time if you use a dummy variable `x1 = 0.5*np.abs(x-0.5)` and do that once, instead of the many times in the loops.

Comment: @ssm First of all thanks for pointing that out, I've actually tried it just now and it does indeed lower the computation time. I must have confused with other cases where there aren't significant for loops. However, although it did make it faster, changing that isn't really enough, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0):

You can probably gain a bit by introducing

```
 y_ik = 1/2 (x_ik - 1/2)
```

The terms in the double sum then become

```
1 + |y_ik| + |y_jk| - |y_ik - y_jk|
```

If the signs of y_ik and y_jk are opposite this equals one, so we can drop all those terms. If the signs are the same it equals

```
1 + 2 min(|y_ik|, |y_jk|)
```

which is also simpler than the original term.

Observing that the terms in the other sum equal

```
(1 + 2 |y_ik|) (1 - |y_ik|)
```

we can save a tiny bit more by precomputing

```
z_ik = 1 + 2 |y_ik| = 1 + |x_ik - 1/2|
```

(downside: we still need to remember the sign of y_ik)

The terms in the double sum then become

```
min(z_ik, z_jk)
```

if the signs of y_ik and y_jk are the same and can be omitted if the signs are different.

The terms in the other sum become

```
1/2 z_ik (3 - z_ik)
```

Comment: Although it seems to be nice to have such modifications, I don't see how this will remove the for loops of the calculations as it still requires to account x_ik (or x_jk) individually.